# How to reconstruct a distorted and pixelated image using python opencv for face recognition

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I have a `python` `face recognition` where I am using `open-face` model and `SVM` to detect and recognize faces. It seems to be working for good quality images but I also have very low quality images which are very `distorted` and `pixelated`. The general steps I am following to recognize image is below:

1. Detect face using face detection model: Reason for using open face model instead of HAAR cascase is that cascade is not able to detect side face
2. Extracting face embedding: Extracting the 128 d face embedding using open face model
3. Training: Using `SVM` I am training the face embedding with appropriate label like below:

   `params = {"C": [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0, 1000.0], "gamma": [1e-1, 1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4, 1e-5]}`

   `model = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel="rbf", gamma="auto", probability=True), params, cv=3, n_jobs=-1)`

   `model.fit(data["embeddings"], labels)`
4. Testing: Extracting the face embedding of the test image, and predicting the results like below:

`model.predict_proba()`

Above steps are working fine when the images are of good quality. But when the images are like below:

[image]

Now I have `unknown dataset` which also contains some distorted images of random persons and I have the image datasets of above known person. If I pass test image of above person, I am getting good result but if I pass unknown person image, it is getting recognized as above person with quite a good confidence score. Due to which I think this happening because the image quality is not good.

Can anyone please point me to some good resources or article where this type of face images are used for recognition. Is there any way we can improve the quality of the image to get better results. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried instructing the computer in a loud and clear voice to "enhance"?

Comment: @TomDalton Sorry didn't get you by enhance. By enhancing do you mean resizing.?

Comment: I mean something along these lines: https://youtu.be/I_8ZH1Ggjk0?t=24